# nftables counter for nat'ed traffic

Tags: nat, nftables

When setting up a counter for a rule in a 'type nat hook prerouting' chain with dnat on a specific port, the counter will only count the initial packet for that rule and the following packets from that same conntrack will not be counted anymore.

I could setup a counter on the forward hook, but it would have to be based on the post dnat destination IP/port. However, I want the counter to apply on the pre-dnat IP/port, because I could have other IP/ports dnat'ing to that same destination IP/port and I want to distinguish the counters based on pre-dnat destination IP/port. Is there a way to achieve that?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate rule with a counter in a chain of type filter in the prerouting hook, but with an earlier priority than -200 (NF_IP_PRI_CONNTRACK) will count all packets of the conntrack.

Therefore, only set a counter in the dnat rule if you want to count the packets that trigger the DNAT.